# Can we change "rowSelection" dynamically in Ag-grid angular?

Tags: ag-grid-angular

I am displaying data using Ag-grid in angular 8 with checkbox in first column. I need to set **rowSelection:"single"** to allow single data edit at a time and need to switch it to **"multiple"** for allowing download multiple selected data. Lets say I have two buttons *"Edit"* and *"Download"*.
How can I switch this attribute "single" to "multiple" and vice-versa dynamically on clicking these two buttons? Or what would be another way to handle this situation.

Any suggestion or solution would be appreciated. Thanks

Example: